# Print instruction mnemonic per code line in Valgrind output

Tags: profiling, valgrind, opcode

I am a new user of Valgrind, and so far I know that I can analyze the output file like in the example below:
"A single call to the swap function requires 15 instructions: 3 for the prologue, 3 for assign to tmp, 4 for copy from * b to * a, 3 for assign from tmp and 2 more for the epilogue".

```
    . void swap(int *a, int *b) 
    3,000  {
    3,000      int tmp = *a;
    4,000      *a = *b;
    3,000      *b = tmp;
    2,000  }
```

That information is great, but is it possible to get the exact instructions (mnemonics) that where utilized/executed 
per each line like in the example below? This information would be really valuable to me.

```
    . void swap(int *a, int *b)
    3,000  {                    [insta, instb, instc]
    3,000      int tmp = *a;    [insta, instb, instc]                
    4,000      *a = *b;         [instd, instd, insta, instc]
    3,000      *b = tmp;        [instc, insta, instb]
    2,000  }                    [instc, insta]
```

Example source (http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/guide_callgrind.html)

Best Regards,
Raul.

Comment: kcachegrind (qcachegrind) GUI viewer has disassembly view for output of callgrind and cachegrind tools of valgrind (valgrind-based profilers). As I know, kcachegrind uses external call to objdump and parses it to get the mixed view. `callgrind_annotate` tool has no option to select assembly listing. (PS: You must remember, that valgrind is simulator and it simulates different CPU pipeline. Your Intel is Out-of-order CPU and may execute up to 4 instructions per clock, every instruction is translated to half, one or more microoperations)

Answer (score 0):

Kcachegrind (qcachegrind, http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/) GUI viewer has disassembly view for output of callgrind and cachegrind tools of valgrind (valgrind-based profilers).

As I know, kcachegrind uses external call to objdump and parses its output to get the mixed view with counters for individual instructions and with machine code disassembly.

The `callgrind_annotate` tool (used in the your example) has no option to select assembly listing according to docs http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#cl-manual.callgrind_annotate-options (and there is no such support in the source code of this script).

PS: You must remember, that valgrind is simulator and it simulates different CPU pipeline. Your Intel is Out-of-order CPU and may execute up to 4 instructions per clock, every instruction is translated to half, one or more microoperations. So, you can get "*A single call to the swap function requires 15 instructions*", but 15 instructions mean not 15 CPU clock cycles of real CPU.

PPS: Your page  http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/guide_callgrind.html says in Tips

> The per-function annotation is often too coarse to be useful, the line-by-line counts are key for getting more helpful detail. You can even drop down to observe event counts at the assembly level. Build the code with assembly-level debug information by editing your `Makefile` to include compiler flags `-Wa,--gstabs -save-temps`. Then when running `callgrind`, use the option `--dump-instr=yes` which requests counts per assembly instruction. When annotating this output, `callgrind_annotate` will now match events to assembly statements. Cool!